# Where to keep 'logout' option in windows 8 surface tablet native app?

Tags: windows-8

This may look like very basic question but I am observing different implementations so the question arises.

I am designing wireframes for Windows surface native app. It is assumed that user will rarely use logout. I had kept logout initially on app bar as shown below:

[image]

But considering [windows guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx), it should not be on the app bar.

> **Don’t put login, logout, or other account management commands in the app bar.**
>   All account management commands, like login, logout, account settings, or create an account should go in a Settings flyout. If it's critical that people log in on a particular page, provide the login button on the app page.

Now it says to keep it in settings flyout. But wont it seem to user that its a global logout as this settings flyout is displayed across all apps from right to left on the swipe?

This app does not have any other setting related options. Please suggest appropriate location for logout.  Providing images as examples will be more easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Guidelines for login controls (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965453.aspx) this can be read:

> ## Logout UI
>
> Once users have logged into the application, they should have a familiar and reliable place in the system where they can log out of the application, if necessary.
>
> Avoid putting a persistent logout UI on the app's canvas. The Settings fly out for the app is the right place to enable the user to log out. Once the user has logged in to the app, logging out happens rarely, if the app is delivering meaningful personal content.

This means that you should place the logout functionality in the local app settings (sorry for the Swedish).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I had kept logout initially on app bar

I wouldn't place a logout option in the app bar as app bars are context sensitive to the particular page you are on.  **Windows Guidelines on this:** '*...each page should only contain the commands that are relevant to that page* ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx

> wont it seem to user that its a global logout as this settings flyout
>   is displayed across all apps from right to left on the swipe

The settings panes are dependant on the currently running app. When open it will display your app name at the top of the pane so users should be aware that any settings pane they open from there will be related to your app rather than a 'global logout'.

**For example:**
[image]

**Alternative to settings pane**

If you're not happy keeping logout in the settings pane as suggested by Windows (maybe it's too hidden away there and you need to give it more visibility). Then one option is to place a user button in the top right of your app - on every screen. When tapped a drop down could display with the logout option. Similar to the Windows start screen:
[image]